# Removing an entire "figure" element from my HTML source code

Tags: javascript, html

I am using CKEditor 5 for a major part of my application, and rather than hiring a developer to learn how to build a whole plugin just to stop CKEditor5 from heavily modifying tables, I am working on a way to implement some alternative methods.

One of the things that I see that CKeditor5 constantly does is wraps my tables in a `<figure class="table">` form, which screws up the way it's presented to the user (it has margins, etc. all kinds of stuff I didn't ask for).

Therefore, I am just trying to figure out how to remove an HTML element but keep the data from within. For example:

```html
<figure class="table">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</figure>
```

I just want to remove all `figure` elements from my entire HTML page. How do I accomplish this since there is no ID or class tags for me to reference?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the `figure` elements and get a reference to its parent element as you find them. Then, move the `figure` contents so that it is a child of that parent instead. Then delete the (now empty) `figure`.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Find all the figure elments and loop over them
  document.querySelectorAll("figure").forEach(function(fig){
    const parent = fig.parentElement;    // Get a reference to the figure parent
    parent.innerHTML = fig.innerHTML;    // Move the contents to the parent
    fig.remove();                        // Remove the figure
  });

});
```

```css
figure { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click to remove the figures</button>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, you could also more simply (and more HTML semantically correctly) leave the `figure` and just restyle them to not include margins or padding.

```css
figure { margin:0; padding:0; } /* Just style them the way you want. */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div>
    <figure class="table">
     <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
               <figure class="image"><img style="width:auto; max-height:350pt; max-width: 675pt" src="[link-here]"></figure>
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><strong>test</strong></th>
            <th>test</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
   </figure>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```